# How to add a piece of code to a backgroundWorker that is triggered by click?

Tags: c#, winforms, click, backgroundworker

I need to work with a lot of file.copy, this makes my form1 "not responding" and my program show DeadLock exception, so I want to create a backgroundWorker to handle all the main processing.
**What I did:**

Button:

```
if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy != true)
            {
                backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
```

DoWork:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
        bool continueWork = true;

        while (continueWork)
        {
            if ((worker.CancellationPending == true))
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (string name in listFiles) //global list
                {
                    string destwithFilename= dest + "\\" + Path.GetFileName(name);
                    try
                    { File.Copy(name, destwithFilename, false);}
                    catch (Exception EX_NAME)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(EX_NAME);
                    }
                    worker.ReportProgress((1));
                }
                pbStatus.Increment(50); //Error, I can't access form1, another thread.
                continueWork = false; //If job is done, break;
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Problems:**

1) Form1 still appear as "Not responding";

2) Form1 can't be accessed;

3) Even with a backgroundWorker, DeadLock exception still appears. //Maybe I should disable Managed Debug Assistants

### EDIT

DoWork

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
        bool continueWork = true;

        while (continueWork)
        {
            foreach (string name in Files) //Global
            {
                if ((worker.CancellationPending == true))
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    string destwithFilename= dest + "\\" + Path.GetFileName(name);
                    try
                    {
                        File.Copy(name, destwithFilename, false); //no overwritting
                        worker.ReportProgress((1));
                        //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
                    }
                    catch (Exception EX_NAME)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(EX_NAME);
                    }
                }
            }
            continueWork = false;
        }
    }
```

ProgressChanged:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        pbProcess.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        if (pbProcess.Value == pbProcess.Maximum)
        {
            cbFinal.Checked = true;
        }
    }
```

**Result:**

Output is really slow, but now my form continue the work without "not responding".
pbProcess does not increment, I'm not sure why.
pbProcess is a progressBar.

Comment: For the second problem (can't access the form from anotehr thread), you should use the ReportProgress() method of the backgroundworker object to update the progress and register to the [ProgressChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged.aspx) event in the calling form to update the progress bar state.

Comment: Yes, I already did that. But the something that I don't understand is that my form still happens to be "not responding" even working with backgroundWorker. :/

Comment: You should query CancelationPending in the foreach loop so you can actually stop the file copy operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To report the progression, you should :

- Set the `WorkerReportsProgress` property to True
- Report the progress using the `ReportProgress()` method of the backgroun worker
- And then, handle the `ProgressChanged` event of your background worker. and set the value of your pbStatus

**Code :**

*Report the progression*

```
backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(50);
```

*Handle the ProgressChanged event*

```
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
      pbStatus.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}
```

**Progression**

And for progression, you are reporting the progression using ReportProgress(1), this set the value of your progress bar to one, and does not increment it by 1

```
int cpt = 1;
int totalFilesCount = listFiles.Count;

foreach (var field in listFiles)
{
      // Copy the file ...

      backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress((cpt / totalFilesCount) * 100);
      cpt++;
}
```

Comment: pbStatus.Value = e.ProgressPercentage; //Right?

Comment: Yes : pbStatus.Value = e.ProgressPercentage; // I thought it was a method

Comment: Does the problem of your From1 persist ?

Comment: Not anymore, I changed my code, but now ProgressChanged don't work... I'll put my code.

Comment: Using your code, I put a breakpoint... 
e.ProgressPercentage is Always Zero.

Comment: As the main problem of my code is already solved, although I don't know why, I'll put this answer as accepted. Thanks for the input.
Regarding ProgressChanged, I'll ask another question on this site.

Comment: You are welcome, about progression value, if the result of the ((cpt / totalFilesCount) * 100) expression is not an integer, the progress abr value will not change.